# String with an apostrophe not being updated in mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I am using prepared statements to preform an update. But for some reason a string that contains an apostrophe does not get updated. Is there a way where I can update a string ans preserve  the apostrophe??

Below is an example of my query

```
$query = "UPDATE items SET item_name = ? , item_price = ? WHERE id = ? ";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);

    foreach($items_and_prices as $id => $item_and_price){
        $item = $item_and_price[0];
        $price = $item_and_price[1];
        $stmt->bind_param("sdi",$item, $price,$id);
        $stmt->execute();

    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "*not being updated"*? I suggest you add the following just before creating your `mysqli` connection ~ `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`

Comment: When I update the values in the input field and then page gets refreshed it doesn't show the string with the apostrophe. 

For example if the string is originally "Your" and I update "Your" to "You're". The string will show "Youre" omitting the apostrophe.

Comment: How are you displaying the record? Also, you shouldn't be using `bind_param()` in the `foreach` loop. You can bind parameters right after the call to `prepare()`

Answer (score 0):

The reason that your strings aren't inserting correctly is because apostrophes are special characters. The best way to go about inserting special characters into mysql databases, is to escape them in some way first. With PHP, you have quite a few different options.

I will explain some of them here:

- `htmlentities();` Converts special characters to html entities.

  Usage: http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php
- `htmlspecialchars();` Converts special characters to html special character codes (ie: `&nbsp;`)
  Usage: http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php
- `addslashes();` Escapes special characters with the backslash `\`
  Usage: http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php

Example: `$safestring = addslashes($orginalstring);` would cause all special characters to be escaped with a `\`, causing `'` to become `\'`, making it possible to insert special characters into the database.

You can also use `stripslashes();` to get rid of the `\` escaping when outputting code that has been escaped with `addslashes();`

Comment: No. Just No. The OP is using prepared statements so escaping is unnecessary. Even if it were appropriate he should be using `mysqli_real_escape_string()` which is locale-aware, not the crude and unreliable `addslashes()`. `htmlentities()` and `htmlspecialchars()` have nothing to do with it - they're for encoding data at _output_ so that HTML special characters are displayed, not interpreted.

Comment: @MikeW `htmlentities()` would allow the apostrophe to safely be entered into the database without throwing an error, which is what the OP is looking for. These functions are far from crude, they do a very good job in making special characters safely usable in PHP scripts and queries

Comment: @pattyd Using a prepared statement with bound parameters allows apostrophes (among other potentially unsafe characters) to be safely entered into the database without destroying the original value as `htmlentities()` would do.

Answer (score 0):

@MikeW @Phil  htmlspecialchars did the trick. I needed to to wrap the value string using htmlspecialchars.

For example

```
<input type=text name="category_name" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($category_name, ENT_QUOTES) ?>">
```

Its really important to specify the ENT_QUOTES  after htmlspecialchars. Without it wouldn't work.

Thanks for your help guys